# I need an accurate, comprehensive and idiot-proof OOD tutorial to help me avoid Global variables in C#

Tags: oop

Can anyone point me in the direction of a very good online OO Design (and Programming) tutorial or resource ?

I appear to have badly designed a small AP in C# and now want to sort it out before I go any further and frustrate myself even more.

I did try to do it quickly and only went over a small and insignificant (now I realise) tutorial on OODP and C# and classes etc and not given it the importance, and time, its obviously needs.

Actually, a good C# tutorial would be helpful too - I only read the C# Programming guide (Public Beta Release), a very old book - 2000/1.

More haste less speed etc. doh

Thanks, George.

Comment: I would suggest posting some sample code that can be looked at and some recommendations made on what you can do to fix it.

Comment: Well its the code I am having problems with. I have an initial window/form where the user enters some data and choices. I then have a 2nd window that shows progress thru various tests done on some equipment attached to the PC. I need to access some of the "choices" from the initial window.

I am a pre-historic Cobol, assembler (a small amount) and REXX etc programmer and am not overly familiar with OOD quite yet.

I am/was a very good programmer, honest, but I am finding doing even the most simple of things in C# to be quite frustrating and quite illogical or non-intuitive.

Comment: Actually I have worked with a lot of Cobol (and Fortran) programmers in my time, they have all made the transition without too much hair falling out. The major thing to remember about OOP is that it is still linear programming (ignoring events, threads, etc) its just that we are encapsulating parts of that logic into bite sized pieces to shuffle around. If the global var thing is really throwing you for a loop, start by designing a "master" class which holds all that stuff, and then pass that around.

Comment: Hmmmm, perhaps a deeper understanding of the whole Class structure is required as I was unsure just exactly how to define the number of classes I needed in my design.

I will pay attention to this when going thru the recommended tutorials in the morning, since its 2.30 am in Aberdeen, Scotland, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I have pointed people to both of these resources before, they are a little basic but they over some good high level overviews:

1. [Learning C# and OOP](http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/1445631/Learning-C-and-OOP-Classes.htm)
2. [C# an Object Oriented Introduction](http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/csharpclasses.htm)

A lot depends on your skill level and how you design programs in general (your background etc).

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I have designed and programmed since 1987 using various languages, but this is my first ap using .NET, OOD and C#. The design was quite simple to come up with as its all quite linear, however, C# does not like how I used to do things !

Comment: I think possibly my problem is that I dont have any of the C/C++, Java or VB experience that seems to be assumed in a lot of the resources that I have found so far.

Comment: Hi again,
I wwent thru the 1st tutorial you suggested (I found the whole thing and did it all actually) and found it very useful.

It explained everything very clearly and I realised the full importance of Classes in OOP (yes I know now *blush*).

The previous tutorial, while still accurate, did not even imply the huge imporatance of Class in the whole structure of OOP which of course lead me to design more in my previous ways and didnt create new appropriate classes.

Thanks for all your help in this humbling experience !! Serves me right for rushing at first !! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It will come with experience. One of my favorite ways to learn is to have a senior coder with 20+ years of experience to tear my code apart. No pain - no gain. The book knowledge goes into one eye and comes out of the other ... Post some code here, damn it!

Comment: Yes, I am quite a stickler for getting things right too. Unfortunately I am an unemployed IT guy with nobody to help me out at the moment and am doing this little project for a local engineering company just to get some experience that will look good on my CV.

So I have been floundering about a bit with this.

But I now have the time to look into this properly and spend the next few days getting to grips with as much of this as I can.